# DBGP Implementation C/C++

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, xdebug

Is there a Library that implements XDebug's [DBGP](http://xdebug.org/docs-dbgp.php) in C/C++?
I'm interested in wrtting debugger and if such library exists will save me a lot!
I want to add the debugger to my editor coded in C++ Language but it is an editor for PHP Files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None Exists. There was one from GSOC (App not a library) but I cannot take time to read and convert to my needs plus its written for wx2.8
So I will roll a class to Just glue up with my Editor

**Edit**
I ended using that one as I said.
Inside there is buggy libDBGp but I will fix it myself huh!
If you are interested its [here](https://github.com/LawnGnome/dubnium) (thanks to GitHub)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few GDB based libraries that help debugger frontend writers like libgdb. DBGP is a very stupid and protocol with very small feature set - not enough for debugging C++.

For windows there is nothing like this. You can read the PDB database but it's pretty difficult. I spend a week to see how far i can get but wasn't very successfull. only the theory is easy. It might be better to write a frontend for the command line debugger windbg just like in the old days where you had to do this for GDB.

Comment: Am Updating my question, I want to write editor in C++ but it will be editing php

Comment: If you ask just for a client library in C/C++ you will have no luck. This side is so esay to write and you will immediatly get it glued togehter with your editor and GUI implementation. Doesn't make sense. Just take an expat as an xml parser and start coding your program.

Comment: All am trying to avoid is messing up with sockets, sending messages and receiving back. XML part does not bother me!